# Testing queues in ActiveMQ using Stomp Ruby Client?

Tags: ruby, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to test the following scenarios in ActiveMQ.

1. Establish/Open a connection with ActiveMQ
2. Validate if "Queue_name" is available in ActiveMQ
3. If found, print the # of entities available in "Queue"
4. Validate and print the messages from the "Queue"

I am not concerned on how the data gets published. I have looked for ways to access the queue and read data from it using stomp ruby client but could not find a definite answer. Most of the examples I found online were for publishing and subscribing to events.

Would really really appreciate any help in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

To gain insight into the state of destinations on the ActiveMQ broker via STOMP you can make use of the [StatisticsBrokerPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) feature to query for stats on destinations.  ActiveMQ can also send out information via [Advisory Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) which you can subscribe to with you STOMP client.  As far as the Ruby syntax, no idea, but I'd hope the project has some examples you can build on.